# How to iterate through Folders and sub folders of a Sharepoint Document Library using web references

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am trying to access Folder names from Document Libraray using web services in C#.
I am to get the first level folder names using getlistitems.
Howvever i am not able to get sub folders and documents.
Can any body help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SiteData's EnumerateFolder method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774758.aspx